# Is + a proper for phone number regex?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I found in some code regex for phone number:

```
re.sub('[^+0-9]', '', phone_number)
```

But I am wondering if `+` is really needed in there because it is a special character which say: "matches the previous element one or more times".
Can someone tells if this regex is correct and if not, then what is wrong with it?

Comment: This is a pattern used in `re.sub` (deleting all symbols other than `+` or digits). What are *your requirements*, goal? It may be correct or incorrect only in relation to some requirements.

Comment: Also the + is no special character inside a character class

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex,

```
re.sub('(^\+\d{10})', '', phone_number)
```

Comment: Why should OP use this regex? OP has no issues with the regex, OP has a problem defining the requirements.

Comment: Matching? Then why do you provide code that *replaces*?